# RidNotFoundException in Baasbox Server

Tags: playframework-2.0, orientdb, baasbox

I started receiving RidNotFoundException a few days back.I can find the documents in the baasbox admin panel . But when I search them through api it says RidNotFoundException.

When I tried to take a database backup it showed error and said some records are corrupted and stopped taking backup.

I am really stucked. Here is the message shown:

```
{"result":"error","message":"RidNotFoundException: UUID 664fa522-e1b8-4c6f-91d7-5c38e7e7a6c0 not found","resource":"/document/myapp/664fa522-e1b8-4c6f-91d7-5c38e7e7a6c0","method":"GET","request_header":{"Accept":["*/*"],"Host":["localhost:9000"],"User-Agent":["curl/7.35.0"]},"API_version":"0.9.5-snapshot","http_code":404}
```

I am running BaasBox-0.9.5 in a droplet with 512 MB Ram and 20 GB disk space. The database folder has occupied 332 MB storage.

What can I do ?

Comment: About the RID you could use repair database console command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I investigated baasbox log . From their I found that it was failing to reindex the records.

So I connected the database with an orientdb-1.7 console. While trying to rebuild from their I found an inconsistent record was causing it. It had the same id as the next record. Probably due to some error a duplicate record was created. So I deleted one of them . Voila !!!